# Inner join on multiple tables produces error

Tags: mysql

I have three SQL tables and I am trying to get the list of `department id`, `average employee age`, `the range of employee salary(min-max)` and the `total number of employees` as a table.

```
Emp ( eid : INTEGER, ename: STRING; age: INTEGER; salary : REAL ) 
Works ( eid: INTEGER, did: INTEGER, pct_time: INTEGER ) 
Dept ( did: INTEGER, budget: real, manager_id: INTEGER )
```

I am using the left join to find the total number of employees in each department as following and it works.

```
SELECT d.did, COUNT(e.eid) AS total_employees 
FROM works d LEFT JOIN works e ON e.did = d.did
GROUP BY d.did;
```

But when I try to find the minimum salary for the department MySQL gives an error.

```
SELECT w.did, COUNT(e.eid) AS total_employees, e.salary
FROM works w LEFT JOIN emp e ON e.eid = w.eid
GROUP BY w.did;
```

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sqlw1.e.salary' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by mysql> SELECT w.did,
>   COUNT(e.eid) AS total_employees, e.salary FROM works w LEFT JOIN emp e
>   ON e.eid = w.eid

Can someone tell me what's the mistake of trying to access the salary here? Also, I'd appreciate your comment on how I can join these three tables to obtain the column values.

Comment: You have missed to add this field 'e.salary' in group by clause.

Comment: use  `SELECT w.did, COUNT(e.eid) AS total_employees, MIN(e.salary)`

Comment: all non aggregated columns must be in the group by.

Comment: listen to jitendra; he/she is correct

Comment: Know your RDBMS: `mysql`<>`sql-server`. I've removed the incorrect tag for you.

Comment: @Emdad I finally want the table to be grouped by w.did adding e.salary to the `GROUP BY` seems to give the wrong answer.

Comment: You can and the `MIN(e.salary)` in select and `GROUP BY` w.eid

Comment: @Fawzan, I think your problem will be solved as "Silva" mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this type of query either you have to put column into `group by` or you have to use some aggregate function on column.

You need to change your query to

```
SELECT w.did, COUNT(e.eid) AS total_employees, MIN(e.salary)
FROM works w LEFT JOIN emp e ON e.eid = w.eid
GROUP BY w.did;
```

Here we are using `MIN()` function to fetch the minimum `e.salary`

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the MIN salary of employee so you need to group by employee id,

Try with below query.

```
SELECT w.did, COUNT(e.eid) AS total_employees, MIN(e.salary) AS salary
FROM works w LEFT JOIN emp e ON e.eid = w.eid
GROUP BY w.eid;
```